# Show that the left ideal $(N_G) \subset F[G]$ is a simple submodule of $F[G]$, where $N_G = {\sum}_{g \in G} {g} \in F[G]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, ideals, group-rings

I am trying to solve this Representation Theory question:

Let $F$ be a field and $G$ a finite group. Let $N_G = {\sum}_{g \in G} {g} \in F[G]$. Show that the left ideal $(N_G) \subset F[G]$ is a simple submodule of $F[G]$.

Any help would be highly beneficial. Thanks :)

Comment: You might start by seeing what $g\cdot N_G$ is for an arbitrary $g\in G$. From there, maybe you can describe what $(N_G)$ is?

Comment: Please try out the site's search function first, next time. I think you would have found the linked duplicate.

Comment: @rschwieb thank you for pointing this out - I am new to the stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Show that the left ideal $F[G]N_G=FN_G$, and you will have shown that it is $1$-dimensional as an $F$-subspace, and that is necessarily a simple left module.